# Xamarin Forms Shell GotoAsync

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using the Shell template from VS2019 in a Xamarin Forms app.I have two pages listed in the shell flyout.

```
<FlyoutItem Title="Home" Icon="icon_about.png">
       <ShellContent Route="HomePage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomePage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
<FlyoutItem Title="Logoff time" Icon="icon_about.png">
       <ShellContent  Route="SecondPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate 
        local:SecondPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

Using the hamburger menu I navigate away from the Homepage to another page SecondPage. I have a button on the SecondPage which perform an action and from that action I want to navigate back to the HomePage. When I use this code:

```
var route = $"{nameof(HomePage)}";
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(route);
```

The HomePage shows but there is a back button instead of the hamburger menu. If I tap the hamburger icon the page navigates back to the SecondPage.
How do I navgate from SecondPage to HomePage and show the hamburger icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two

```
//
```

before the route will accomplish my aims.This resets the root page  apparently so HomePage once again become the root page.

```
var route = $"//{nameof(HomePage)}"
```

Answer (score 1):

With so little information (not knowing the details of how your navigation is implemented) it's hard to help you. But the first things that come to mind are the following you could try.

Try one of the following for popping the SecondPage and navigating back to:

```
await Shell.Current.Navigation.PopAsync();
```

or

```
await Shell.Current.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
```

And if you have a navigation bar with a back button that you don't want then try this in the HomePage.xaml

```
NavigationPage.HasNvaigationBar="False"
```

or

```
Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
```

Comment: Added some extra code hopefully make it easier to understand. Just want to navigate from second page to homepage and show hambuger menu NOT back button.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue in my own project; I wanted this page to show up at the start of the application, using the navigation class to push the screen and then pop it when the user clicks a button. I had the same issue of a back button showing up, instead of the hamburger icon, when moving the user to the HomePage. I hope this helps someone in the future.

Classes are as follows:

```
public partial class AppShell : Xamarin.Forms.Shell {
        public AppShell() {
            InitializeComponent();
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ItemDetailPage), typeof(ItemDetailPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(NewItemPage), typeof(NewItemPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(HomePage), typeof(HomePage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(NewUserPage), typeof(NewUserPage));
            this.Navigation.PushAsync(new NewUserPage());
        }
}
```

```c#
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class NewUserPage : ContentPage {
        public NewUserPage() {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = new NewUserViewModel();
            Shell.SetNavBarIsVisible(this, false);
        }
    }
```

```
class NewUserViewModel : BaseViewModel {

        public NewUserViewModel() {
            NewUserClickedCommand = new Command(OnNewUserClicked);
        }

        public Command NewUserClickedCommand { get; }

        private async void OnNewUserClicked() {
            await Shell.Current.Navigation.PopAsync();
        }
    }
```

And the XAML file for NewUserPage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Project.Views.NewUserPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="This is a page for new users"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
            <Button Text="Click for New User" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}" Command="{Binding NewUserClickedCommand}"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```